# A count of all duplicate rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to find out how many of my rows are duplicates with any other row in my table.

Any help would be really appreciated

```
Select *
From DB
```

This gives me a count of all rows but I can’t figure out how to get only duplicates

Comment: `Select * From DB EXCEPT ALL Select DISTINCT * From DB`

Comment: Do you have any id to declare rows as duplicated or you need to compare the whole line ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide more details then I can only answer in generic terms. You could create a query like this:

```
select
    custom_key,
    count(0) as occurrences
from
    table
group by
    custom_key
having
    occurrences > 1
;
```

with `custom_key` being the field or fields which make a record unique or not.